# Colorbox loading, but no images..?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to load images directly from 500px photosite.

This is my code for loading the colorbox:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#photogrid").find('a').colorbox({rel:'lb', transition:"fade"});
});
</script>
```

As Isaid, it seems that colorbox is loading, but I am left with the just the overlay on the page and an empty 'black' square where the image should be...

The images are collected from within the `id:photogrid`, collecting all with a DOM element of `a`. Each of the images is an `http://link-to-image` - pretty standard.

I'm thinking that the loading script is set up incorrectly, but searching GOOGLE has not brought up any answers for me!!!

---

OK, so I added `photo:true` to the `.colorbox({options})` that seemed to work...

Now I'm getting random visibility of the images?  Here is a link to the website:
http://staringatthesky.info/#photogrid

I'm using latest Chrome browser under Win10.

---

It all seems rather random, and if I clear the cache, no issues, but if I return to view a second time = missing images...

I have a number of other scripts on the site and it could be a conflict, but that would be beyond my knowledge..!

Comment: Could you supply a link to a page where we can see this not working?

Comment: console is your friend Matt

Comment: I'd looked at the page loading under the Network tab and in the console and it's not throwing any errors that I can see..?

Comment: First you had this >> `$("#photogrid").find('a').colorbox({rel:'lb', transition:"fade", photo:true, scaling:true, current:"image {current} of {total}", previous: "<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>", next: "<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>", close: "<i class="fa fa-close"></i>",});` and was throwing an error first time i checked it

Comment: now I rechecked it and that long line became this >> `$("#photogrid").find('a').colorbox({rel:'lb', transition:"fade", photo:true});` !!!!!!

Comment: Yup, I was thinking I could add other `options`, but it broke and I went back to what had worked...

Thanks for looking though :) Is there a correct order for options..? Was I using correct syntax..?

Comment: not the order, but you needed to replace outer *double* quotes with *single* quotes in `previous` and `next` and `close` -*or you could escape the inner double quotes with backslash like this `\"`, also you had an extra comma at the end

Comment: Because they're not `strings` correct..?  Thanks for the help again, it's a learning process.

Comment: Seems to be working, not showing those extra options I added. But that's another issue for me to solve.

Comment: compare this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/m3sqoj77 to this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/m3sqoj77/1 , check  the console in both and see how in the first link the "syntax" coloring for `var foo = "<p id="p1">example text 1</p>"; differs from the second link `var foo = '<p id="p1">example text 1</p>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was these lines:

```
    previous: "<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>", //double quotes conflict 
    next: "<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>", //double quotes conflict
    close: "<i class="fa fa-close"></i>", // extra comma
});
```

extra comma at the end, and you didn't escape double quotes in those 3 lines, change them to:

```
    previous: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
    next: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
    close: '<i class="fa fa-close"></i>'
});
```